# why is \$P^{max}_{R3}=\frac{V^2_{th}}{4R_{th}}\$,not \$P^{max}_{R3}=\frac{V^2_{th}}{R_{th}}\$,why should we have to multiply \$R_{th}\$ with \$4\$?

Tags: power, resistance

The question ask me the power that R3 consume,here is the schematic and my calculation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdabRL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My calculation:

I modify the left part of the circuit,V1,R1 and R2, to this,and use the differential the find that if the R3 is 9 ohms,we can get the max power that R3 consume,and i can know the current  which flows through the R3 is \$2A+\frac{8}{4+3+2+9}=2A+\frac{4}{9}A=\frac{22}{9}A\$, so \$P^{max}_{R3}=I^2R=(\frac{22}{9})^29=\frac{(22)^2}{9}=53.77\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flySyd.png)</sup>

\$V_1^{new}=V_1^{old} \times \frac{12}{12+6}=12 \times \frac{12}{18} =8V\$

\$R_1^{new}=R1 // R2=6//12=4\$ ohms

the current  which flows through the \$R3:2+\frac{V_1^{new}}{4+3+2+R}=2+\frac{V_1^{new}}{4+3+2+9}=2+\frac{8}{18}\$

But the answer of the \$P^{max}_{R3}\$ is not right,the solution said that :

\$R_{th}=9,V_{th}=22\$,and when the R=9 ohms,it can have the  \$P^{max}_{R3}\$
,and the  \$P^{max}_{R3}=\frac{V^2_{th}}{4R_{th}}=\frac{22^2}{4\times 9}\$

I want to ask  why is \$P^{max}_{R3}=\frac{V^2_{th}}{4R_{th}}\$,not \$P^{max}_{R3}=\frac{V^2_{th}}{R_{th}}\$,why should we have to multiply \$R_{th}\$ with \$4\$?

Comment: _" i can know the current which flows through the R3 is 2A+4/9A=22/9A"_ how do you know this? If R3 is disconnected, what is the voltage at R4?

Comment: what?why do you think R3 is disconnected?

Comment: Your task here is the find the Vth and Rth seen form the R3 resistor perspective. Therefore to find Vth and Rth you need to disconnect R3 from the circuit. So we have Vth = 2A*(3Ω + 4Ω) + 8V = 22V and Rth = R1 + R5 + R4 = 9Ω.

Comment: Also, do you know the maximum power transfer theory? Pmax occur when Rth = RL https://www.tutorialspoint.com/network_theory/network_theory_maximum_power_transfer_theorem.htm

Comment: @G36 I know how to calculate the R3 value,but i don't understand why the power is \$V^2_{th}/4R_{th}\$,not  \$V^2_{th}/R_{th}\$

Comment: @G36 as i said,i use the differential the find that  the R3 is 9 ohms,and we can get the max power that R3 consumes

Comment: OK, in this case, you know that Rth = R3 so try to find the power dissipated across R3 resistor. Can you do it? PL = (Vht/2)^2/(R3) = (1/2^2 * Vth^2)/R3 = (1/4 * Vth^2)/R3 = Vth^2/(4*R3) =Vth^2/(4*Rth) because Rth = R3 and V_R3 = Vth/2

Comment: Why do you think   \$V_{R3} = Vth/2 \$? In my thinking,i can't understand why is this ,\$P^{max}_{R3}=I^2R \times 9=(\frac{22^2}{9})\$, wrong?

Comment: Notice that if Rth = R3 we have a voltage divider, thus the voltage drop across V_R3 is V_R3 = Vth x R3/(Rth + R3) = Vth x Rth/(Rth + Rth) = Vth x 1/2 = Vth/2. Do you see it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring your error in calculating Vth, here's why the power is divided by 4.

Vth is the voltage at R4 with R3 disconnected, ie. the 'source' without a 'load'. In this case it is:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRmqir.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now we attach a 'load' with resistance equal to Vth, and what happens?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhkPKH.png)</sup>

The output voltage halves.

\$P = \frac{V^2}{R}\$. With half the voltage \$P_L = P_{th} = \frac{(V_{th}/2)^2}{R_{th}}\$.

\$(1/2)^2 = 1/4\$, so moving it to the bottom of the equation we get \$P = \frac{V_{th}^2}{4R_{th}}\$

In words:-
 The voltage is divided by 2 so the power is divided by 4 (compared to what it would be if Rth was 0 Ω).

Comment: thanks for your  reply ,can you also tell me where is wrong about my calculation?because in my thinking,the power of R3 should be the \$P^{max}_{R3}=I^2R=(\frac{22}{9})^29=\frac{(22)^2}{9}=53.77\$,why is my answer not the same as the solution?where am i wrong?

Comment: @shineele Your answer is wrong because the voltage drop across R3 resistor is not equal to 22V but 11V instead.

Comment: @G36 so you mean the my calculated current is wrong,so my answer is wrong?

Comment: @shineele Exactly, This current is equal to I = Vth/(Rth + R3) = Vth/(2Rth)